# Exception while rendering controller in symfony 2 while form error is happening

Tags: php, symfony, twig

whenever a form error is throwing 
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("") in VetAdminBundle:layout:base.html.twig
this error is throwing.
i have done this in my layout.

```
{{ render(controller("VetAdminBundle:Default:adminmenus")) }}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: when you render a twig file you should mention the extension of the file; `adminmenus` should be `adminmenus.html.twig` (for example)

Comment: OP [renders](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers) a controller, he does not [include](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/include.html) a view.

Comment: @Javad "VetAdminBundle:Default:adminmenus.html.twig" for URI "/_fragment" is not callable i am getting this error

Comment: @AlainTiemblo what do u suggest i should do for dynamic menus from database with acl

Comment: @Rahi Do you know where the twig file is located? What's your controller name?